# PUT command Snowflake on VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-connector, sqltools

I use the snowflake driver for SQLTools on vscode and i'm connect to my snowflake account but i'm some issues when i want to put some files with extensions .csv from my local machine to my stage in snowflake. Indeed, when i use the command `put file:///mypath/file.csv @nameofmystage;` it works on terminal but not in the window vscode with extension Snowflake driver. However, others commands like `copy into` works on the driver vscode ...

The error's message is Unsupported feature 'unsupported_requested_format:snowflake'

thanks in advance for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not a solution or final answer, but a hint - here someone is having the same error, but with the Go-Driver: https://github.com/snowflakedb/gosnowflake/issues/227

Go didn't support PUT in this case.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an answer for SQLTools, but if you are using Snowflake's Visual Studio Code extension, PUT is supported.

https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=snowflake.snowflake-vsc

Answer (score 0):

Based on the [PUT](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/sql-reference/sql/put.html#put) documentation, currently PUT is not supported in .NET driver.

[Snowflake Driver for SQLTools](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=koszti.snowflake-driver-for-sqltools) does not look like a driver from Snowflake, as it was not mentioned here:

[Connectors & Drivers](https://docs.snowflake.com/en/user-guide/conns-drivers.html)

I am not sure how the driver is built, but given both vscode and .NET are both MS product, I assume that it is not supported, but hope others can help to verify.